Find the relationship between a, b and c in the figure bellow.
In the figure, if $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{MN} = 90^o$, calculate the relationship between a, b and c.
(Answer: $b^2=a^2+c^2$)

I try:

$HP=r_1: OP=x_1: DQ=r_2 :OQ=x_2: OM=r\\
 \triangle OPH :(R−r_1)^2-r_1^2=x_1^2⇒r_ 1=\frac{R^2−x_1^2}{2R}\\
 R=x_1+a: r_1=\frac{a(2R−a)}{2R}$
Similarly $\triangle OQD: r_2=\frac{c(2R−c)}{2R}$

There is a fairly simple trig bash. Are you looking for a completely synthetic solution?

@DS Please, post your solution

$r_1=\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta+1}$ where $\theta=\angle HOP$ and $R=1$ might help, but it gives a solution similar to D S's.

WLOG, the circle's radius is 1. Let $\angle MOA = \theta, \angle IOB = \theta '$, where $\theta$ and $\theta'$ are complementary.
Let $OP = x$. Then $$x(\tan \theta + \sec \theta) = 1 \iff x = \sec \theta - \tan \theta$$
Similarly $\sec \theta ' - \tan \theta ' = OQ := y$.
Then we have
$$\begin{align}
a^2+c^2 &= (1-x)^2+(1-y)^2 \\
&= (1-\sec \theta + \tan \theta)^2+(1-\sec \theta ' + \tan \theta ')^2 \\
&= 2 + \tan^2 \theta + \sec^2 \theta + \tan^2 \theta ' + \sec ^2\theta' +2(\tan \theta+\tan \theta' - \sec \theta - \sec \theta' - \sec \theta \tan \theta  - \sec \theta' \tan \theta')\\
&= 2\ \underbrace{\tan\theta \tan \theta'}_{=1} +\tan^2 \theta + \sec^2 \theta + \tan^2 \theta ' + \sec ^2\theta' + 2(\ \underbrace{\sec\theta \sec \theta' }_{= \tan\theta+\tan \theta'}-\sec \theta \tan \theta  - \sec \theta' \tan \theta' - \underbrace{\sec\theta\tan\theta'}_{=\sec \theta'} - \underbrace{\sec\theta' \tan\theta}_{= \sec \theta}\ ) \\
&= (\sec\theta - \tan \theta + \sec \theta' - \tan \theta')^2 \\
&= (x+y)^2 \\
&= b^2
\end{align}$$
